# CheckedTextView in ListVew - setChecked() does not work for Android 2.3

Tags: android

I have a `ListView` which specifies a `listSelector`:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Every list item has a `CheckedTextView`:

```
 <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/checkedTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CheckedTextView" />
```

I need that when clicking on a row from list, the clicked item to remain checked, this is how I do it:

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
// .... 
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    CheckedTextView checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.checkedTextView);
    checkedTextView.setChecked(true);
}
```

It works fine on Android 4.0, but does not work on Android 2.3. Would appreciate if you could give any clue why this is happening.

Comment: Using `ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE` as choice mode, you don't need to check/uncheck it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why its happening but i have an idea to implement it in another way

Assuming your are using custom adapter to load list items

set OnClickListener for CheckedTextView at the time of view creation in your custom adapter

```
final CheckedTextView ct = (CheckedTextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.checkedTextView);
ct.setText("text");
ct.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // do what ever you want to perform here
        if(ct.isChecked()){

        } else {

        }
    }
});
```

another option [here](http://blog.rochdev.com/2011/08/checkedtextview.html)